# How do I make one table column fill all the spare horizontal space?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table consisting of 3 columns. It has a fixed width of 600px.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
    <td>Actions</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the Qty and Actions columns to be as small as possible (keeping the content to one line) and the Name column to take up the rest of the available space. The size of the Qty and Actions column change depending on content/font size so fixed widths will not work in this case.

Is there a way of doing this in HTML/CSS? Or is this something I need to break out the Javascript for?

Comment: did you try using nowrap?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp .
Note that the attribute is deprecated, and should be used with css, as specified there

Comment: This doesn't solve my main problem, which was that the other two cells were too wide, not too narrow. But along with Ranta's answer, it's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can apply width="99%" on that column. For example:

```
<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td width="99%">Name</td> 
    <td>Qty</td> 
    <td>Actions</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: This works great, as long as I use nowrap on the other cells. I feel a little stupid for not thinking of it now. Thanks

Comment: the width attribute is also deprecated, and css should be used instead: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_width.asp

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. In Webkit browsers, this will squish images that don't have the width set explicitly.

Comment: You're a genius. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: Note this doesn't work with table-layout: fixed. With a fixed table-layout the column will actually get 100% of the width.

Answer (score 4):

you can use max-width:99%; on the first column and give fixed sizes on the other columns (I used pixels sized columns).

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="max-width: 99%">
      Will max
    </td>
    <td style='width:110px;'> 
      fixed size here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

For every column you want to be the minimum width: (1) set the CSS width to zero and (2) use `white-space: nowrap` to prevent the text from wrapping onto multiple lines.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

:where(th, td):not(.max) {
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* For demo purposes */
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="max">Name</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="max">Victoria Adelaide Mary Louisa</td>
    <td>233,546,443</td>
    <td>Abort Retry Fail</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```