# How to adjust an stretchable ol and an absolute block inside a fixed container

Tags: html, css

i have a parent container .secondary-nav-wrap having css

```
.secondary-nav-wrap {
    margin: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

It contains an ol having variable li's and an absolute positioned div .import-26-as having css code

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Now when there are three li's everything is fine

[image]

but when number of li increases to 5 or 6 (max), the Import div is overlapped with the li i.e

[image]

I am trying to achieve a design like this where yellow div automatically positions itself accordingly.

[image]

I am completely fine if yellow div overflows out of the parent div

Edit:

Code for li is

```
.primary-nav li, .secondary-nav li {
float: left;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
max-width: 190px;
}
```

Code for ol is

```
.primary-nav, .secondary-nav {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: auto!important;
margin-left: auto!important;
position: relative;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

CSS code for yellow div is

```
.import-26-as {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0%;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Helvetica,Arial;
font-size: 12px;
color: #4c4725;
height: 34px;
overflow: hidden;
-moz-transition: height 150ms ease-out;
-o-transition: height 150ms ease-out;
-webkit-transition: height 150ms ease-out;
transition: height 150ms ease-out;
}
```

the parent div is wrapped inside a container div with css

```
.container {
width: 950px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: provide code please !!

Comment: everything is provided

Comment: yes but only css, where is html part?

Comment: please have a look at image, i have shown the html through inspect element

Comment: well you did not get me..if you want solution then you have to provide html+css, no one will try to read html from images..try to understand or read how to ask question on stackoverflow..thanx

Answer (score 1):

Another option is quantity queries. I have added the css code for min 3 and max 6. you can check it by adding/removing secondary li's. you can fine tune my code, I just created it for testing.

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.primary-nav-wrap ol{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.primary-nav-wrap ol li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 19px;
    width: 111px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
}
.secondary-nav {
    margin: 0;
    width: 700px;
}
.secondary-nav li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    width: 190px;
    background-color:#999999;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #7A7EF1;
}
ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+4), ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+4) ~ li {
    max-width: 145px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+5), ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+5) ~ li { 
    max-width: 120px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+6), ol.secondary-nav li:nth-last-child(n+6) ~ li { 
    max-width: 105px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.import-26-as {
    width: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    float: right;
}
 .import-26-as a {
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro",Helvetica,Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #4c4725;
    height: 34px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="primary-nav-wrap">
           <ol class="primary-nav">
               <li><span class="test">link 1</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">link 2</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">link 3</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">link 4</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">link 5</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">link 6</span></li>
           </ol>
       </div>
       <div class="secondary-nav-wrap">
           <ol class="secondary-nav">
               <li><span class="test">A. test test 1</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">B. test test 2</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">C. test test 3</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">D. test test 4</span></li>
               <li><span class="test">D. test test 4</span></li>
           </ol>
           <div class="import-26-as"><a href="">other link</a></div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There're options.
1. You could use a table (even emulate with `display` property assigned `table` for parent, `table-cell` for `ol` and inner `div`).
2. You could give give inner `div` `display: inline-block` and `float: right`.
Either way, you don't need absolute positioning.

UPD: for `table` approach, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138605/how-do-i-make-one-table-column-fill-all-the-spare-horizontal-space)'s an answer about how to give maximum width to `ol`. It works with `display: table-cell`.